# Matlab's simplify behavior

Tags: matlab, simplify, symbolic-math

I'm trying to simplify some symbolic equations.

```
>> syms x;
>> simplify(sqrt(x^2)/x)

ans =

(x^2)^(1/2)/x
```

Actually, I want matlab to return 1 or smth like that.

```
>> simplify((x^9+7*x^8-2*x-6)/(x-1))

ans =

-(- x^9 - 7*x^8 + 2*x + 6)/(x - 1)
```

1 is a root of numerator, so I want matlab to reduce that fraction.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is that `(x^2)^(1/2)` can't be simplified unless you know a little more about `x`, for instance `x>1`.

Comment: Well, for (x^3)^(1/3) it also doesn't work.

Comment: x^(1/3) is also multi-valued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer for the first question is simple.

```
>> x = sym('x', 'positive' )

x =

x

>> simplify(sqrt(x^2)/x)

ans =

1
```

Answer (score 3):

For the second question, you might have to help show Matlab the way:

```
>> factor(x^9+7*x^8-2*x-6)

ans =

(x - 1)*(x^8 + 8*x^7 + 8*x^6 + 8*x^5 + 8*x^4 + 8*x^3 + 8*x^2 + 8*x + 6)

>> ans/(x-1)

ans =

x^8 + 8*x^7 + 8*x^6 + 8*x^5 + 8*x^4 + 8*x^3 + 8*x^2 + 8*x + 6
```